# How to study convergence of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am just thinking of how would a sequence like this one behave:

$$a_1=2$$

$$a_2=2^{\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

$$a_3=(2^{\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}})^{\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

$$a_4=(2^{\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}})^{\sqrt[3]{2}})^{\frac {1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}}$$

$$\vdots$$

I could define general terms, or at least even and odd ones, but it is easy to see how would a sequence continue. Is it convergent? And is there only one accumulation point?

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer** (too long for a comment):
Let us define this using a recursive sequence. If we write $a_2$ as $(a_1)^{2^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$, $a_3$ as $(a_2)^{2^{+\frac{1}{3}}}$ and so on, then we notice the exponent is $\frac{1}{n}$ for $a_n$. The sign of the exponent is positive for odd $n$, and negative for even $n$, so we can write it as $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Putting it all together, we have the base value $a_1 = 2$, and $a_n$ as $$(a_{n-1})^{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{n}}.$$

I am not sure how to solve this recurrence, but searching it on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(1)+%3D+2,+g(n)+%3D+g(n-1)%5E(+(-1)%5E(n%2B1)+*+1%2Fn)) suggests that it converges to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_2<a_4<a_6<...<a_7<a_5<a_3<a_1$ so the sequence converges.